# Using crc32 to find if files were harmed or damaged

Tags: ubuntu, files, checksum, integrity

I have a directory with a content. To ensure nothing will get lost with copying I compressed the directory and now I have a `dir.tar.gz` file.

The copying still troubles me and the files are damaged so I would like to find out if it is due to compressing or copying on the files,  so I generated a `crc32` of the compressed file.

I am not able to generate the `crc32` of the original content of this directory which means I cannot use `crc32` on it. Is it possible?

Also if I manage to compare these two numbers , if they are the same that means that files were not harmed?

Answer (score 5):

Depending on how "strict" you want the checksum to be, a typical Linux install provides at least three options:

1. `sum` - this is a quick and simple checksum.  It's not cryptographically secure and so deliberate tampering would be possible, but it should handle file copying errors well enough.
2. `md5sum` (sometimes just `md5`).  This calculates an MD5 based checksum on the file.  This is slower than `sum` but more resilient.  The MD5 algorithm has been broken, but it's not easy.
3. `sha1sum` This calculates an SHA1 checksum; even slower but the strongest against tampering.
4. `crc32` This may not be present on all systems; it's a perl program.

In your use case I'd probably stick with `sum`.

By calculating the checksum on the `tar.gz` before transfer and after transfer you have reasonable assurance that the transfer was good (`sum` and `crc32` are weakest, but good enough).

There's another possibility... since you're compressing the data then you can try and decompress the result at the other end with `gzip -dc file.tar.gz > /dev/null`.  If this generates an error then the file is corrupt, otherwise it's good.   Depending on the size of the file this might be easier because it doesn't require a second file to be transferred.  It may not fit your use case, though.

Comment: +1.  See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hash_functions and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122982/robust-and-fast-checksum-algorithm